# flask-admin when to use @action decorator and when to use @expose decorator

Tags: flask, flask-admin

So i am now on a project where i have to customize flask-admin interface. I see two decortors that are important. The @expose decorator and the @action decorator. so my question is, where is the difference between them. For me it looks like they can do the same things. When o use @action and when to use @expose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@expose is used for rendering views onto one object, eg show/edit a user.

> Use this decorator to expose views in your view classes. [Link to documentation](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_base/#base-view)

@action is used for rending views on more than one object, eg Adding a user to a course (school).

> Use this decorator to expose actions that span more than one entity (model, file, etc) [Link to documentation](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_actions/?highlight=%40expose#module-flask_admin.actions).

For more understanding (im not an expert) read the [Flask-admin documentation](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It is highly recommended that you have a read and understand it, especially if you have joined a project that involves using flask-admin.